# Primitive Central Idempotent

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation, noncommutative-algebra

I'm reading the proof of this theorem and there's one part that bothers me a bit.  The theorem and the proof of that part (highlighted), are below.
[image]

Proof of Highlighted Part:

[image]

The definition, given in the text, of primitive central idempotent element $e$ is if $e$ is central and has no proper decomposition as a sum of orthogonal central idempotent elements.

The part that confuses me is I don't see how $e  = e e_i + e(1-e_i)$ implies that $ee_i = e_i$ or $ee_i = 0$.  It seems like the author was using the fact that $e$ is a primitive central idempotent to conclude this but in the statement we only assume $e$ is a central idempotent.

Also, assume that $e$ is a primitive central idempotent, then $e  = e e_i + e(1-e_i)$ would imply that either $ee_i = 0$ or $e(1-e_i) = 0 $ but this would imply that $e = ee_i$ though.

Maybe I'm missing some trivial thing here but I don't see it.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if the author has a typo or if I'm the one missing something, but we can write

$$e_i=ee_i+(1-e)e_i.$$

This is a sum of orthogonal central idempotents, and since $e_i$ is primitive, one of the terms is zero. Thus either $ee_i=0$ or $(1-e)e_i=0$, in which case $e_i=ee_i$.

Comment: oh, ok, I think that makes so much sense, I don't know why I didn't catch it before,  thank you so much!!